# Regulating power on load

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, analog

I have a blackbody emitter, for which I have to regulate the temperature (to get a constant spectrum out of it) - the only way to do this in our system is to regulate its power (we can't measure its temperature, we can assume that the ambient temperature is constant).

Additional info: the emitter is switched periodically on and off.

The current design only sets the voltage across the emitter with a DAC, and this is ok as long as its resistance does not change. It looks like this:
[image]

We would like to compensate for changes in \$R_L\$. It would be possible to measure the current digitally and adjust the voltage, but I would prefer an analog solution. E.g. we set a voltage on the DAC and it sets \$P_L\$ of the load.

I know of the voltage controlled current sinks (like in [AN-31](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=snla140&fileType=pdf&keyMatch=an-31&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything)), but in this form it is not suited for the task. I don't know whether it can be modified to regulate the power of a load by adding some additional inputs. Any google search gets me to power supplies, which is also not what I need.

Can anybody point me to a reference circuit or a simple IC would be even better. How is this task called - so that I can make a google search for it?

Comment: What's wrong with a voltage-controlled current sink? What do you mean by "in this form"?  Why can't you measure the temperature of the black body...that seems like the best idea by far.

Comment: Can't measure temperature, because the optical system attached to it does not allow it. There is no internal temperature sensor and the case is kept at constant temperature.

Comment: Can't use the current sink, because if I regulate the current flowing through, the voltage on the load changes. I need to regulate voltage and current at the same time somehow.

Comment: You're controlling the voltage with a DAC, so just measure the current. Since you now know both the voltage (because you set it) and the current (because you measure it), you know the power dissipated by the device. Adjust the voltage accordingly until you reach the power you desire.

Comment: Yeah, that's the backup plan, but its additional ADC sampling and signal processing, which would leave us less processor time for the real task and thus probably reduce our signal quality.

Comment: Of course the voltage across the load changes when you change current...Mr. Ohm says it must. Your job is to regulate both of these to get constant power.

Comment: That's what I meant. I edited the question, maybe it is less ambiguous this way.

Comment: It's way easier to regulate power digitally, especially since you're already controlling the voltage with a DAC.  If you're worried about processor cycles, get a faster processor.  It will save you headaches in the future.  [Though is there no way you can point an IR temp sensor at the back body?]

Comment: You could add a small dedicated microprocessor for this function to not use up time in your main processor.

Comment: What are the approximate voltage/current/power you need to hit?

Comment: @G.B. You should talk a lot more about the situation you face. I've no idea if you've considered (or even if it might apply) the idea of a disappearing filament pyrometer. These are very easy to use. But maybe your temperature range doesn't fit. When I worked on Wehnelts for electron beam lithography, for example, the emitter lifetime was very very highly dependent on *actual* temperature. Customer A would keep an emitter running 2 yrs while customer B's would last 2 mos. Both using a $10k current source instrument. But customer A took the time to use specialized calibration periodically.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to control the current is to control the voltage.  If you don't want to do this digitally, and your FET can handle some dissipation, put in a current sense resistor and differentially measure the current through the resistor and the voltage across the load.  An analog multiplier will take these readings and output power.  Compare your power reading to a reference designating the desired power with an op amp (with the reference on the positive input), and use the output from that amp to drive the FET gate.  Make sure the driver stage is slow enough to prevent instabilities from delays in the other components, particularly the multiplier.

Comment: Do you think this can be made stable?

Comment: I think it can, since a heater is probably going to be a primarily resistive load, and you're not trying to modify the target power.  The I-V characteristics are probably going to be changing in response to the temperature of the device, so they'll be pretty slow.  Just make sure the loop is slow enough...again, the stage driving the FET is probably good for that filter.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple circuit which drives a constant current through the load.  If you would be willing to measure the voltage at the load you can calculate the voltage drop and multiply it times the constant current which will give you power.  You then adjust Vdac to maintain the power level.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the precision current sink from AN-31. But if I am setting the voltage digitally, I can omit this current sink and simply adjust the DAC voltage so that the set voltage times measured current is constant.

Comment: You need to know both voltage drop and current to calculate and control power.  If you omit the current source, you will have to measure current since RL can drift, therefore is not known.

Comment: Help me understand, why are you using a DAC to set the voltage if you are unwilling or unable to measure the current or load voltage?  You have no feedback so why have digital control?

Comment: The previous designer did not think about aging/resistance change. The DAC is there to allow us to set an approximate power once, during calibration.

Comment: I am beginning to think your load is remotely located where you cannot get feedback so you want a local circuit to regulate power.  The analog circuits you need may be subject to drift, so you are back to needed adjustments.  I think you may be better off using a small micro to read voltages and currents at the load and control the power locally.